# Make a sprite follow a path using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, path, sprite

I'm doing a project for computing in college, and I've hit a bit of a stumbling block.

I'm making a tower defense game, and I need to make a sprite (in this case in the form of a picture box) follow the path set out. I tried looking online and on these forums for an answer, but almost every one I find uses XNA or some other add on, or is in another coding language. Since we have to use the college computers, installing anything else isn't an option, it has to be just the standard C# frameworks. I tried to find an alternative for waypoints, or storyboards, but my search bore no fruit.

If anyone could help me at all I would be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: If you already know how to place a bitmap in WinForms you should be able to get the moving along a path part from any of the XNA samples. E.g. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273396/animate-sprite-along-a-curve-path-in-xna

Comment: He's not using XNA - he just quoted it as a "everyone I find uses it". That said, I suspect the "right" answer might have something to do with a timer control, and LERPing from one waypoint to the next. =)

Answer (score 0):

I would fill in more details, but seeing as how it's homework I guess I will just provide an outline:

```
  PictureBox pbox1 = new PictureBox();
  Point[] path = { new Point(10,100), new Point(150, 60), new Point(100, 120)};
  Timer timer1 = new Timer();
  int curPointIndex = 0;
  int nextPointIndex = 1;
  float percent = 0f;
  float pctIncrement = 1f;

  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     pbox1.Location = path[0];
     pbox1.Size = new Size(32, 32);
     pbox1.BackColor = Color.Red;

     timer1.Interval = 20;
     timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
     timer1.Start();

     this.Controls.Add(pbox1);
     this.components.Add(timer1);
  }

  void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     percent += pctIncrement;
     // Calculate weighted average based on point number
     // curPointIndex and nextPointIndex in path here.

     // Set pbox1.Location to calculated position here.

     // Check for altering curPointIndex and nextPointIndex here when percent
     // reaches 100 (and reset percent) here.
  }
```

I have filled in the code in my test project and it works.  The one caveat is that the sprite will move more slowly between points that are close than it will between points that are far apart, but I'm not sure if that's a problem for you requirements.  If it is, you could change pctIncrement to be a calculation inversely proportional to the distance between the current point and the next point.

Answer (score 0):

I already added one answer but I also have a completely different answer.  You say that you don't want to use third party frameworks, and I'm not sure if this crosses the line or not.  [Scrolling Game Development Kit 2](http://sgdk2.sf.net/) will let you define maps and sprites and paths for sprites to follow, but then it will generate a totally stand-alone project that can be loaded into Visual C# Express and compiled independently if you so choose.  The one library it does rely on is OpenTK, just to access OpenGL to handle the drawing of graphics.  That part may cross the line, but it's primarily for the drawing which is encapsulated mostly in Display.cs.  It's not for managing the state of any sprites or maps or movement.